# Error adding ownProperty objects to Object's prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was adding some properties to objects using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). It works normally when I add to the property of the object. But when I added it to the prototype of the object, I got a `too much recursion` error.

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj.__proto__, 'key', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: () => {return key},
    set: (value) => {
        if (typeof(value) == 'number'){
            key = 2*value;
        }
     }
});
obj.key = 3;
console.log(obj.key);
```

Why can't objects in the prototype be added this way?

Comment: where is `key` defined? (it matters)

Comment: @dandavis, It's not defined earlier. I was using the setter as initialisation. But even even if I define it in the prototype, I get the same error.

Comment: you can't define it there, you need a closured private variable named key (as shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by defining the property on the Object's prototype every object gets that getter / setter. And everything in JS is an Object so this means `window` is also going to have a `key` setter / getter.

Inside your setter / getter functions you just use `key`. Since you did not explicitly define a `key` variable it is going to use the one defined on `window`. This is what is causing the recursion.

You do `obj.key = 3`, which calls the setter which does, `window.key = 2*value`, which calls the setter, which does `window.key = 2*value`. So on and so forth till you reach maximum call stack.

Don't add something onto the prototype unless you are wanting it on every instance.

And since you are using arrow functions there is no `this` bound to the setter / getter calls and therefore you have no way of knowing which instance object you are interacting with.

Instead do not extend Object's prototype make one of your own, and set / get to the right variable / property.

For instance use actual constructor functions, and change arrow functions to regular function expressions. This will make it so the setter / getter can get a instance reference to the object. You will then need some way of keeping track of which key belongs to which instance. If not needing to hide these variables you could simply use prefixed named property, like: `this._key = 2*value;` Otherwise you can use [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)s if you want to keep them private.

```js
function YourClass(){};

(function(){
  var keyMap = new WeakMap();
  Object.defineProperty(YourClass.prototype, 'key', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function(){
      return keyMap.get(this);
    },
    set: function(value){
      if(typeof(value) == "number"){
        keyMap.set(this,2*value);
      }
    }
  });
})();
obj = new YourClass();
obj.key = 3;
console.log(obj.key);


function secondClass(){}

//make secondClass inherit from YourClass
secondClass.prototype = Object.create(
  YourClass.prototype,
  {
    "constructor": { 
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: secondClass
  }
});

var obj2 = new secondClass();
obj2.key = 16;
console.log(obj2.key);
```

Also since you seem ok with using ES6 you could just use Classes which have a set / get syntax

```js
class YourClass {
   constructor(){
      this._key = null;
   }
   set key(value){
      this._key = 2*value;
   }
   get key(){
      return this._key;
   }
}

class SecondClass extends YourClass {
  constructor(){
    super();
  } 
}

var obj = new SecondClass();
obj.key = 17;
console.log(obj.key);
```

Comment: I need to add it to all objects that will inherit from this one, to it has to go to the prototype. Can you give a working example of how I can add it to the prototype without causing this kind of a recursion?

Comment: I was wondering why global variables were causing the recursion issue until I noticed the mention of `window`. That's honestly quite an amusing bug, and a perfect example of why fiddling with `prototype` (or the non-standard `__proto__`) is not recommended for beginners!

Comment: @TheChetan, see updated answer. Showed a couple examples first one that uses ES5 inheritance using constructor functions. The second using ES6 classes syntax.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, Thanks for the awesome answer! I knew it was some issue for the window object, but I could not get a proper working example. But hey, I'm never gonna get good without playing with the real stuff